# R: Generate dynamic names for dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic, names

I need to read several csv files from a directory and save each data in separate dataframe.
The filenames are in a character vector:

```
lcl_forecast_data_files <- dir(lcl_forecast_data_path, pattern=glob2rx("*.csv"), full.names=TRUE)
```

For example: "fruc2021.csv", "gem2020.csv", "strb2021.csv".

So far I am reading the files step by step:

```
fruc2021 <- read_csv2("fruc2021.csv")
gem2020 <- read_csv2("gem2020.csv")
strb2010 <- read_csv2("strb2021.csv")
```

But there are many more files in the directory and subdirectories. To read them all one by one is very tedious.

Now I have already experimented a little with the map function, but I have not yet figured out how to automatically generate the names of the dataframes from the file names.

A first simple try was:

```
lcl_forecast_data <- lcl_forecast_data_files %>% 
  map(
    function(x) {
      str_replace(basename(x), ".csv","") <- read_csv2(x)
    }
  )
```

But this did not work :-(

Is it even possible to generate names for dataframes like this?
Or are there other, simpler possibilities?

Greetings
Benne

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Have you considered using `list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`?? Then you could use `lapply` to read through the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use a list and lapply as @Onyambu suggested you can use assign() to generate the dataframes.

```
filenames <- c("fruc2021.csv", "gem2020.csv", "strb2021.csv")

for (i in filenames) {
    assign(paste('',gsub(".csv","",i),sep=''),read.csv(i))
}
```

Comment: Wow, so easy, thanks pookpash.
The for loop works great.